# Live Video Keying with Flash (AS3)? How to do that?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, actionscript, live

For a new project, I want to take a video feed, filmed in a greenscreen room, and as you see it, do a color keying, to kill the green and show an alternative picture on the background.

Is there a way to do this with Flash, AS3?

optional question: If a button is clicked, the now new constructed Picture should be saved as a Jpg. Any Idea?

Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing you're going to need to use Pixel Blender: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html and possibly Alchemy as well http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/

Sorry I can't give you more info than that as I've never worked with them before.

To capture a screen grab, it's easier. Create a new `BitmapData` object the size that you want your final image. Use the `draw()` method on it to capture the stage (or holding clip etc). Grab the as3corelib from here: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib and use the `JPGEncoder` or `PNGEncoder` class to create a jpg or png (personally I prefer png, as even though the filesize is bigger, it's much quicker to generate as you don't need to worry about compression).

Then, use the `FileReference` class ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) to save it out (`JPGEncoder` and `PNGEncoder` both return your image as a `ByteArray` so just pass that as the data to the `FileReference.save()` function).